# Example of a map with an orbit of period 6

Tags: real-analysis

What would be an example of a map with an orbit of period 6 but no odd orbits?

I think I have to show something like $f^6 (x) = x$ and find prime points of the map. Then i have to show that $f^3, f^5$ does not have fixed point. Do i have to show that $f (x)$ has no fixed point either?

Comment: Map from where to where? Are there any restrictions, such as continuity?

Comment: no restriction actually.

Comment: Then let $A$ be the set of vertices of a regular hexagon, and let $f:A\to A$ be rotation around the centre by $60$ degrees.

Comment: Vertices of a hexagon, then each angle has 120 degrees, and? would you elaborate more?

Comment: Why? (Don't tell me just to know it exists)

Comment: @Zach466920 are you asking me or Andre?

Comment: You of course. I'd have put @person otherwise...(you already know that though that's how you contacted me)

Comment: so why is that why for?

Comment: If you want an equivalent one, let $A=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and let $f(0)=1, f(1)=2,\dots, f(4)=5, f(5)=0$.

Comment: Thanks @AndréNicolas! what would you say about my thoughts in the problem?

Comment: You do need to show that $f^6(x)=x$, for all $x$, where $f^6$ is $f(f(f(f(f(f)))))$. And you need to show that for any odd integer $k$, there is no $x$ such that $f^k(x)=x$. That is taken care of in the examples, since (if we think geometrically) it is clear that applying a rotation through $60^\circ$ $6$ times leaves all vertices alone, and that applying $f$ $k$ times where $6$ does not divide $k$ puts every vertex into a new position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$, and define $f:A\to A$ by $f(0)=1$, $f(1)=2$, $f(2)=3$, $f(3)=4$, $f(4)=5$, and $f(5)=0$.  It is easy to see that every orbit has period exactly $6$.

A more geometric version of the same thing is to let $A$ be the set of vertices of a regular hexagon. If $x$ is such a vertex, let $f(x)$ be the vertex obtained from $x$ by rotating the hexagon (counterclockwise) about its centre.

Comment: How do I show that the orbit does not have odd orbits? Actually I don't know what does odd orbits mean in this case. Could you explain that to me please. Thank you so much for your hints and answer!

Comment: The orbit of an object $a$ under $f$ is the collection of all objects $a$, $f(a)$, $f(f(a))$, $f(f(f(a)))$, and so on. In the examples we are discussing, some elements (indeed all elements) have a finite orbit, since applying $f$ $6$ times to $x$ brings us back to $x$. In the case we have discussed, the orbit of every $a$ has $6$ elements, and in particular not an odd number of elements.

Comment: Thanks! Now I got it! Then, for instance, $f^5 (x)$ would not bring us back to $x$. Thank you so much for your time and helps! Much appreciated!

Comment: You are welcome.  This was just an example, which can be extended to a family of examples.  I took advantage of the fact you put no constraints on the domain of the transformation, or on the nature of the transformation. If we do put restrictions, then things can be quite different. For example, if we think of rotation $f$ about the origin through $60$ degrees as acting on all points of the plane, then $f$ takes the origin to itself, so $f$ has a fixed point, an orbit of size $1$.

Comment: Thanks again for further explanation!